# Error "No such namespace: jdbc" when requiring next.jdbc in Clojure

Tags: java, postgresql, clojure, leiningen

I'm running into require and or next.jdbc errors when I attempt
to create a postgres database:

```
Unhandled java.io.FileNotFoundException
   Could not locate next/jdbc__init.class, next/jdbc.clj or next/jdbc.cljc on
   classpath.
```

and the following. Which appears anytime I attempt to call jdbc functions within the cljblog.db namespace.

```
1. Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
   No such namespace: jdbc
```

Here's my db setup:

```
(ns cljblog.db)
(require '[next.jdbc :as jdbc])

(def db
  {:dbtype "postgresql"
   :dbname "cljblog"
   :host "localhost"
   :user "postgres"
   :password "postgres"})

(def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db))

(def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db))
(def conn (jdbc/get-connection ds))

(jdbc/execute! conn ["
-- postgresql version
drop table if exists posts?;
create table posts (
  id int,
  title varchar(255),
  body text,
author varchar(25)
"])

(jdbc/execute! conn ["
insert into posts(title,body,author)
  values('Working with postgres',
'this is my first attempt at working
with postgres in Clojure', 'Sam Dees')"])

(def result-set
  (jdbc/execute!
   conn
   ["select * from posts"]))
```

and the project.clj

```
(defproject cljblog "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [com.github.seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.2.780"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.5"]]
  :ring {:handler cljblog.handler/app}
  :repl-options {:init-ns clj-jdbc.core}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.2"]]}})
```

*I've truncated the full error messages for brevity.
*postgres is installed with an active server running on the system

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you restarted your REPL after adding those dependencies, your `ns` form should look like this:

```clj
(ns cljblog.db
  (:require [next.jdbc :as jdbc]))
```

In addition, you have:

```clj
  :repl-options {:init-ns clj-jdbc.core}
```

but you didn't show us that namespace (in the file `src/clj_jdbc/core.clj`) which I suspect is where the error is really occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to clone this demo project using Postgres in a Docker container along with `next.jdbc` for access:

https://github.com/cloojure/demo-jdbc-next

Follow along the instructions from the README and it should work right away. There are also examples of using `next.jdbc` with the H2 database.

When you run the tests, you will see everything working:

```
> lein clean; lein test 

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 17
-------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-h2

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-postgres

Ran 7 tests containing 42 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

All of the action is in the test namespaces. The file `test/tst/demo/jdbc_postgres.clj` starts out like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.jdbc-postgres
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [next.jdbc :as jdbc]
    [next.jdbc.result-set :as rs]
    [next.jdbc.sql :as sql]
    ))

; ***** change this value to `false` to disable PostgreSQL unit tests *****
(def postgres-enable true)

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(when postgres-enable

  (def db-info {:dbtype   "postgres"
                :dbname   "example"
                :user     "postgres"
                :password "docker"
                })

  (def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db-info))

  ; NOTE: ***** Must MANUALLY  create DB 'example' before run this test! *****
  ;       In PSQL, do `create database example;`.  See the README.
  (dotest
    (jdbc/execute! ds ["drop table if exists address"])
    (let [r11 (jdbc/execute! ds ["
                create table address (
                  id      serial primary key,
                  name    varchar(32),
                  email   varchar(255)
                ) "])
          r12 (jdbc/execute! ds ["
                insert into address(name, email)
                  values( 'Homer Simpson', 'homer@springfield.co' ) "])
          r13 (jdbc/execute! ds ["select * from address "])
          ]
      (is= r11 [#:next.jdbc{:update-count 0}])
      (is= r12 [#:next.jdbc{:update-count 1}])
      (is= r13 [#:address{:id 1, :name "Homer Simpson", :email "homer@springfield.co"}]))

<snip>
```

I've noticed that you seem to have something wrong in your `project.clj`.  Mine looks like:

```
  :dependencies [
                 [com.h2database/h2 "1.4.200"] ; #todo cannot upgrade yet or crash!
                 [hikari-cp "2.14.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [org.clojure/test.check "1.1.1"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.3.5"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.2.1"]
                 [com.github.seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.2.780"] 
                 [tupelo "22.05.20"]
                 ]
```

so the dependency on `org.postgresql/postgresql` may be part of the problem.

Comment: I updated the `project.clj` to match the postgresql dependency you specified, without success.   Not familiar with Docker, but I'll see if I can get it working, thanks.

Comment: Your coordinates are wrong for next.jdbc Alan -- should be [com.github.seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.2.780"] (which is what the OP has).

Comment: I upgraded all libs (except H2). The demo project runs with the old or the new versions.